# Free calendar sharing with 'non-editing author' permissions

Tags: web-apps, calendar

So, I'll start with a short backstory.

We have a vacation home which we share within the family, and since the extended family is rather large, and only getting larger, we need to find an easier way to manage the booking of the time they wish to stay at the vacation home.

What we're looking for is a way to have a permission for normal users to be able to create their own events, but not able to edit or remove events that they are not owners of. It would also be required that the owners of the calendar should be able to modify all events, almost like an elder council ;). This is what we've found that Outlook(the paid software bundled with the Office suite) provides. We've tried both Outlook(online free version) and Gmail, but neither of them have what we want.

So now we're seeking out a preferably free and simple alternative that provide these two permissions when sharing a calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try [TEAMUP](http://www.teamup.com/). It is free up to 8 users (actually sub-calendars) – I'm not sure if it is enough for you.

It appears to have resource reservation you need including permissions requirements. 
From [four published use cases](http://www.teamup.com/products/use-case-studies.html), part of [second one](http://www.teamup.com/blog/item/use-case-team-calendar.html) appears to be closest to your scenario.

Consult [FAQ](http://www.teamup.com/help/faq.html) and [Tutorials](http://www.teamup.com/help/tutorials.html) for effective start.

Comment: When editing the calendar settings it says we can have a total of 10 sub-calendars, but since there were 2 original, I assume you meant 8 extra.
This is, however, perfect for our needs. We could have different sub-calendars for different accessibility. So a big thank you to you. :D